# How do you create multiple classless networks out of single IPs, then divide them into networks and subnets?

Tags: network, subnet

I'm having trouble figuring out how to create 4 classless networks out of 10.0.0.0/24, then dividing it into 4 equal subnets.

I'm also not sure how to create 5 classless networks out of 20.4.3.8/16, then divide them into 2 networks that can accommodate 50 hosts, 2 networks that can accommodate 25 hosts and 1 network that can accommodate 13 hosts. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/18942/8499) has sections for equal, unequal, and host size subnetting.